# How to move sprite on z-axis in 2D Unity

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I am making a 2D game and I am having trouble in setting up a sprite movement. Here is a picture for reference what I want to achieve:

[image]

Now car is moving forward (I have done that using road and car animations). And time after time a traffic light comes. It gets larger when car comes close to it.
How can I do it in 2D. Because z-axis have no effect on it.
My camera is set to orthographic.

Comment: Things don't get larger when they're closer when using an orthographic camera. You need to use a perspective camera, or apply a scaling transformation yourself.

Comment: @DMGregory I used perspective mode on camera. I placed my sprite on z-axis 30. But when I start decreasing z (move sprite towards camera) the sprite still don't scale.